# c++ Visual studio 2015 shortcut to make function from selection of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Any plug-in that will take a selection of code and will generate it into a method/global function?

Like you can select some code, right click and do 'surround with' to take that code to ifdef, for loop, etc.. but I didn't see any option to create a method/function.

Comment: Try Visual Assist plugin

Comment: Visual Assist seems to have many features but I firstly prefer something with a free license

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 you should have the [Extract Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/refactoring/extract-function) refactoring command available without the need for a plug-in.  In the Edit menu look for **Refactor** (at the bottom) then hover over that and look for **Extract Function**.

Although the documentation says it is experimental the [Dev Labs page for Extract Function](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCppDevLabs.CExtractFunction) says the feature was integrated into Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thanks.  As I check, for now its not seem to work for me. I downloaded the 'C++ Extract Function' from the Visual Studio market place, but I still have just 'Create/Move' at the refactor.  I checked on VS Enterprise with Update 3. I will check more, may it needs an update or something.